# I'm having trouble writing a "For Loop" statement that checks a text file to see if each exist in it

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I'm writing a "for loo" statement that checks a test file to see if the mutiple entered arguments exists. The script I have written just returns the everything as if it exists even if it doesn't

```
for i in "$@"
do
grep -q "$i" /home/s132a18/A10/cisStudents  && echo "$i is a student" || echo "$i is not a student"

done
```

Comment: No I think adding a line break solved it.

Answer (score 0):

When the word `not` is  the only difference:

```
for i in "$@"
do
   echo "$i is $(grep -q "$i" /home/s132a18/A10/cisStudents || echo "not ")a student"
done
```